# How to make changes to a variable inside an if statement

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make changes to a var inside an if statement, for some reason I can not get it to change.

```
func checkIfFieldsEmpty()-> Bool{

    var textfieldStatus:Bool!
    var v = [
        "name" : ""
    ]

    for (key, value) in v {
        if value == "" {
            textfieldStatus = false
        } else {
            textfieldStatus = true
        }
    }

    return textfieldStatus
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code with breakpoints on your lines with `textfieldStatus =...`?

Comment: @bneely when i put a breakpoint there  i get this value String "" 
_core _StringCore 
_baseAddress COpaquePointer 0x000000010be0f328 ""
_countAndFlags UInt 0
_owner AnyObject? nil None

Comment: What I was getting at is, set breakpoints there, find out why execution reached that point, and ensure the outcome is what you want. Basically use the debugger to ensure code correctness.

Comment: @peter, what are you trying to achieve with this?  If `v` has more than one element, then the order it will be iterated is not guaranteed.  However, it's the very last pair of `(key, value)` that will determine the final result.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov u are right that was the error that i ran into. Instead i just placed var fieldErrorCount = 1 then outside of the function if that variable is equal  to 1 that will determine textfieldStatus. Im not sure if theres away to calculate "if Any V is empty then set textfieldStatus = true " but the other work as well thanks

Comment: @peter, if you want to set `textfieldStatus` to `true` if there is at least one element in `v` that has its value equal to `""` and to `false` in all other cases (including just empty `v`), then you can simply do `textfieldStatus = v.contains { $1 == "" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution work well form me

```
 func checkIfFieldsEmpty()-> Bool{
var v = [
        "name":""
        ]

        var textfieldStatus:Bool = true
        var fielderrorCount:Int = 0


        for (key, value) in v{

            if value == ""{
                fielderrorCount = 1
            }
        }


        if fielderrorCount > 0{
           textfieldStatus = false

        }

        return textfieldStatus

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will always return false. If you want to check if the values are completely empty, then I think you want this.

```
for (key, value) in textfield {
    if value == "" {
        textfieldStatus = false
    }else{
        textfieldStatus = true
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and the original message?

Comment: i see what you are saying i was not testing the textfield in the function  i was testing the v

Answer (score 0):

According to @fridgemagnet answer, the difference is you are calling a method which required a Dictionary parameter. But you are always setting a

> var v = [ "name":""]

And you are checking the variable "v" value which should always return false and by default your "textfieldStatus" value is false. So there is no chance to change your "textfieldStatus" value. Please make sure what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

You define `v` as empty, and then check if its empty. Try `v = ["name": "peter"]`(but, it's not really what you want). When you declare `var v = ...`, you are clearing the previous values for `v` if it is defined earlier in the program.